# Delaying javascript DOM change when running background script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, web-worker

I am working on a script that sometimes involves many time-consuming calculations to occur before rendering the result, sometimes just a few. To inform the user that the delay is occurring, a "wristwatch" symbol is shown during the calculation. So far so good. But I don't want the wristwatch to be shown if the delay is very short, as the repeated brief flashing of the symbol can be annoying to view. I can't use `setTimeout()` to delay the display of the wristwatch since that function can't conclude until the sequential calculation operations are completed. 
Reading up here on SO, I found that a Web Worker was advisable to use to get asynchronous behaviour of the calculation operations. But even when relegating the calculations to a Web Worker, the flashing behaviour of the wristwatch persisted. Again, `setTimeout()` couldn't be used to delay the rendering of the watch, as the quick operations were completed before the delay was over. As a last resort, I used `fadeIn()` as a delay method, which worked. But it seems less than elegant to use `fadeIn()`. Is there a more convenient way to achieve this goal?
Below are the html page with script and WebWorker of a demo that show the behaviour during long and short operations, respectively, of the various methods, of which the third gives the desired result in my hands. You can switch between them by commenting out the others.
**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function($){
  const worker = new Worker("asyncWorker.js");
  $("#shortbtn,#longbtn").click(function(){
    $("#done").hide();

    /* METHOD 1 */
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#wait").show();
    },100);

    /* METHOD 2 */
    //$("#wait").show();

    /* METHOD 3 */
    //$("#wait").fadeIn(100);

    let btnId = $(this).attr("id");
    worker.postMessage(btnId);
    worker.addEventListener("message",function(message){
      $("#wait").hide();
      $("#done").show();
    });
  });
})
</script>
<style>
  #wait,#done{display:none;}
  #wait{font-size: 4em;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="shortbtn">Short delay</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button id="longbtn">Long delay</button>
  <div id="div">
    <span id="wait">&#8986;</span>
    <span id="done">Done!</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**asyncWorker.js**

```
addEventListener("message",function(message){
  switch(message.data){
    case "shortbtn":
      for(let i=0;i<1000;i++){let a = 0;}// simulate quick process
    break;
    case "longbtn":
      for(let i=0;i<3*1e9;i++){let a = 0;} // simulate slow process
    break;
  }
  postMessage("done");
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you can't use `setTimeout`. For the case that the work is finished before the timeout, you can simply cancel the timeout and it won't display anything (see [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout)), or check in the callback whether the operation already finished (by checking a variable that tracks the operation status)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @A_A, the solution is to use `setTimeout()` and clear the timeout when the calculation is finished. Maybe that is rather obvious, but I'll keep the question as long as the moderators don't mind.

**From main.html:**

```
/* METHOD 4 */
let tmo = setTimeout(function(){
  $("#wait").show();
},250);


let btnId = $(this).attr("id");
worker.postMessage(btnId);
worker.addEventListener("message",function(message){
  clearTimeout(tmo); // prevents overdue timeout
  $("#wait").hide();
  $("#done").show();
});
```